# Overcoming the void error of for each loop

Tags: c#

Below is a part of a code I'm working on and execution gives the following error.

> 'Cannot implicitly convert type void to string'.

How can I fix that?

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] strArray = new string[n];
    int i = 0;

    foreach (example)
    {
        if (condition 1)
        {
            strArray[i] = output;
        }
        if (condition 2)
        {
            strArray[i] = output;
        }
        if (condition 3)
        {
            strArray[i] = output;
        }
        i = i + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: where (at which line) do you have this exception?

Comment: What is this `foreach (example)` ?, i think you need to read up on [foreach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in)

Comment: also what is `output` and `condition`. you have given us no information

Comment: Please put your actual code in

Comment: Can u please post the full code. It helps to others to help you

Comment: *Cannot implicitly convert type void to string* => you're assigning a `string` variable or array content from a method which has `void` return type. Please provide example what method you want to assign the value.

Comment: Many here are asking for your full code, but I'd rather you posted a [mcve]

Answer (score 4):

When I present you code

> ```
> private static void Main(string[] args)
> {
>     string[] strArray = new string[n];
>     int i = 0;
>
>     foreach (example)
>     {
>         if (condition 1)
>         {
>             strArray[i] = output;
>         }
>         if (condition 2)
>         {
>             strArray[i] = output;
>         }
>         if (condition 3)
>         {
>             strArray[i] = output;
>         }
>         i = i + 1;
>     }
> }
> ```

into .net fiddle, I get:

```
Compilation error (line 1, col 16): Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
Compilation error (line 1, col 33): Identifier expected
Compilation error (line 1, col 35): Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
Compilation error (line 3, col 12): Identifier expected
Compilation error (line 3, col 14): Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
Compilation error (line 3, col 29): Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
Compilation error (line 3, col 38): Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
Compilation error (line 10, col 25): Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
Compilation error (line 11, col 9): Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
```

Surrounding it with

```
public class MyClass
{
    // your code
}
```

leaves me with

```
Compilation error (line 8, col 21): Identifier expected
Compilation error (line 8, col 22): ) expected
Compilation error (line 10, col 23): ) expected
Compilation error (line 10, col 24): ; expected
Compilation error (line 10, col 24): Invalid expression term ')'
Compilation error (line 10, col 25): ; expected
Compilation error (line 14, col 23): ) expected
Compilation error (line 14, col 24): ; expected
Compilation error (line 14, col 24): Invalid expression term ')'
Compilation error (line 14, col 25): ; expected
Compilation error (line 18, col 23): ) expected
Compilation error (line 18, col 24): ; expected
Compilation error (line 18, col 24): Invalid expression term ')'
Compilation error (line 18, col 25): ; expected
```

Fixing the missing `n` and the `foreach` to

```
string[] strArray = new string[10];
int i = 0;

var data = new [] {"1","2","3","4"};
foreach (var example in data)
{
     // your inner code
}
```

leaves me with

```
Compilation error (line 11, col 23): ) expected
Compilation error (line 11, col 24): ; expected
Compilation error (line 11, col 24): Invalid expression term ')'
Compilation error (line 11, col 25): ; expected
Compilation error (line 15, col 23): ) expected
Compilation error (line 15, col 24): ; expected
Compilation error (line 15, col 24): Invalid expression term ')'
Compilation error (line 15, col 25): ; expected
Compilation error (line 19, col 23): ) expected
Compilation error (line 19, col 24): ; expected
Compilation error (line 19, col 24): Invalid expression term ')'
Compilation error (line 19, col 25): ; expected
```

Fixing the inner conditions

```
    if (i==1)
    {
        strArray[i] = "There is";
    }
    if (i==2)
    {
        strArray[i] = "is no";
    }
    if (i==3)
    {
        strArray[i] = "no spoon.";
    }
    i = i + 1;
```

leads to a missing public static Main, fixing that leads to

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] strArray = new string[10];
        int i = 0;
        var data = new[]{"1", "2", "3", "4"};
        foreach (var example in data)
        {
            if (i == 1)
            {
                strArray[i] = "There is";
            }

            if (i == 2)
            {
                strArray[i] = "is no";
            }

            if (i == 3)
            {
                strArray[i] = "no spoon.";
            }

            i = i + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

a program that runs without errors.

No where on the way of this journey *your* error message popped up.

Answer (score 0):

If *output* is a function with a void return type, then you cannot assign its value to the strArray[i]. In every condition, make sure that the return value from the functions is not void.

Also, the problem could be in using the **foreach** so replace it with a for **loop** since altering the enumerator of a *foreach* could generate a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting void type or  `string[] args` inside `Main(string[] args)`

Also (not another solution) but an improvement if you have to put

```
if(condtion==1){...}
if(condtion==2){...}
if(condtion==3){...}
```

etc

Is better practice that you replace it for a Switch so that your program doesn't check a lot of ifs every time your method gets called